# Global message count in modeline in Wanderlust

Tags: email, wanderlust

Does anyone know if it is possible to setup in the modeline globally the total number of unread messages in the Inbox with Wanderlust?

I want to be able to see any and all unread messages in my mailbox from any buffer.

Comment: The following three (3) variables are **buffer-local**:  `wl-summary-buffer-new-count`; `wl-summary-buffer-unread-count`; and `wl-summary-buffer-number-list`.  The last of the aforementioned variables is used in conjunction with the function `lengh` -- i.e., `(length wl-summary-buffer-number-list)` to yield the total messages.  Buffer-local values can be obtained from another location by using something like `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer . . . `  If the buffer containing the buffer-local value is not open, then the value will be `nil`.  You may have more than one summary buffer open . . .

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want?  The sum of unread messages in all mailboxes?  The number of unread messages in the `INBOX` mailbox?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for, the number of unread messages in the INBOX mailbox.